# Problems with dynamic input and dynamic output rule

Tags: python, bioinformatics, snakemake

I have a quick question regarding the use of dynamic wildcards. I have searched the documentation and forums, but have not found a straightforward answer to my query.

Here are the rules that are giving me trouble:

```
rule all:
input: dynamic("carvemeOut/{species}.xml")
shell:"snakemake --dag | dot -Tpng > pipemap.png"

rule speciesProt:
input:"evaluation-output/clustering_gt1000_scg.tab"
output: dynamic("carvemeOut/{species}.txt")
shell:
    """
    cd {config[paths][concoct_run]}
    mkdir -p {config[speciesProt_params][dir]}
    cp {input} {config[paths][concoct_run]}/{config[speciesProt_params][dir]}
    cd {config[speciesProt_params][dir]}
    sed -i '1d' {config[speciesProt_params][infile]} #removes first row
    awk '{{print $2}}' {config[speciesProt_params][infile]} > allspecies.txt #extracts node information
    sed '/^>/ s/ .*//' {config[speciesProt_params][metaFASTA]} > {config[speciesProt_params][metaFASTAcleanID]} #removes annotation to protein ID
    Rscript {config[speciesProt_params][scriptdir]}multiFASTA2speciesFASTA.R
    sed -i 's/"//g' species*
    sed -i '/k99/s/^/>/' species*
    sed -i 's/{config[speciesProt_params][tab]}/{config[speciesProt_params][newline]}/' species*
    cd {config[paths][concoct_run]}
    mkdir -p {config[carveme_params][dir]}
    cp {config[paths][concoct_run]}/{config[speciesProt_params][dir]}/species* {config[carveme_params][dir]}
    cd {config[carveme_params][dir]}
    find . -name "species*" -size -{config[carveme_params][cutoff]} -delete #delete files with little information, these cause trouble
    """

rule carveme:
input: dynamic("carvemeOut/{species}.txt")
output: dynamic("carvemeOut/{species}.xml")
shell:
    """
    set +u;source activate concoct_env;set -u
    cd {config[carveme_params][dir]}
    echo {input}
    echo {output}
    carve $(basename {input})
    """
```

I was previously using two different widlcards for the input and output of the carveme rule:

```
input: dynamic("carvemeOut/{species}.txt")
output: dynamic("carvemeOut/{gem}.xml")
```

What I want snakemake to do is to run the carveme rule multiple times, to create an output .xml file for each input .txt file. However, snakemake is instead running the rule one time, using a list of inputs to create one output, as can be seen below:

```
rule carveme:
input: carvemeOut/species2.txt, carvemeOut/species5.txt, carvemeOut/species1.txt, carvemeOut/species10.txt, carvemeOut/species4.txt, carvemeOut/species17.txt, carvemeOut/species13.txt, carvemeOut/species8.txt, carvemeOut/species14.txt
output: {*}.xml (dynamic)
jobid: 28
```

After modifying my rules to use the same wildcard, as suggested by @stovfl and shown in the first code box, I get the following error message:

```
$ snakemake all
Building DAG of jobs...
WildcardError in line 174 of /c3se/NOBACKUP/groups/c3-c3se605-17-8/projects_francisco/binning/snakemake-concot/Snakefile:
Wildcards in input files cannot be determined from output files:
species
```

Any suggestions on how to address this problem?

Thanks in advance,
FZ

Comment: Try according the Snakemake Tutorial [step-2-generalizing-the-read-mapping-rule](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/basics.html#step-2-generalizing-the-read-mapping-rule)

Comment: @stovfl thanks for your response. 

I have tried using the same wildcard for input and output, but when I call rule all, it cannot determine the wildcard. Error output shown below:

`$ snakemake all`
`Building DAG of jobs...`
`WildcardError in line 174 of /c3se/NOBACKUP/groups/c3-c3se605-17-8/projects_francisco/binning/snakemake-concot/Snakefile:`
`Wildcards in input files cannot be determined from output files:`
`species`

   I will modify my original post to reflect the changes and add rule all.

Comment: The tutorial dosn't use `dynamic`? Strip down your testcase to **only** `rule carveme:`. In this `rule` remove **all** from  `shell`, except the two `echo {...}`. Try and add line by line. You are using **relative** filepath and do `cd ...`, this is contradict. Second you are defining `output` but don't us it?

Comment: True, the tutorial does not use dynamic. This was recommended to me by another user. I was trying to strip down my testcase to only the carveme rule, but the problem is that it has wildcards in its input and output, which means that it cannot be my target rule. Also true that I am not using the output of the carveme  rule, but from what I understand, I need to specify it so that rule all knows where to find it! Could you expand on the relative filepath comment? How does it contradict? Thanks for the help!

Comment: *"the relative filepath comment"*:With `cd ...` you change the root directory. This could lead to, that the realtive filepath `carvemeOut/` is not reachable. It's a guess, as I don' t know how `{config[carveme_params][dir]}` expands to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to have dynamic in your rule all and the rule where the dynamic output is created but not in your last output.

Here is a working example. Given an input file of species as an example `species_example.txt`:

```
SpeciesA
SpeciesB
SpeciesC
SpeciesD
```

The following `Snakefile` will produce dynamically 4 output files

```
#Snakefile
rule all:
input: 
    dynamic("carvemeOut/{species}.xml"),

rule speciesProt:
    input: "species_example.txt"
    output: dynamic("carvemeOut/{species}.txt")
shell:  
    """
    awk '{{gsub(/\\r/,"",$1);print  > "carvemeOut/"$1".txt";}}' {input}
    """


rule carveme:
    input: "carvemeOut/{species}.txt"
    output: "carvemeOut/{species}.xml"
    shell: "cat {input} > {output}"
```

Dynamic has a lot of restrictions currently in Snakemake (<s>only one dynamic wildcard allowed</s> see Francisco's comment below, no mixing of non-dynamic and dynamic outputs in the same rule) hence I avoid it if possible.  For example, instead of making this example dynamic I would have used a pyhton function to produces a list of possible species names before any rule is ran and use that to expand the wildcards in rule all. Are you sure you need dynamic output?

Also, you should avoid writing such long shell portions directly in the Snakefile and use either external scripts or break that shell command into multiple rules.

Comment: thank you! yep this did the trick. I am pretty sure I need dynamic because my pipeline generates clusters based on metagenomics data, and there is no way of knowing how many clusters will be generated beforehand! I am aware that there are sever limitations to dyanamic(), which is unfortunate. Do you think I can avoid using dynamic somehow? Also do you mean to say that I can only have one dynamic wildcard in my pipeline? or do you mean per rule?

Comment: You can only have one dynamic wildcard per pipeline.   Before you had `input: dynamic("carvemeOut/{species}.txt")` and `output: dynamic("carvemeOut/{gem}.xml")` and this wont work as you had `gem` and `species` as dynamic wildcards.  Whether you can avoid using dynamic is hard for me to answer and is highly dependent on how long it takes to calculate how many clusters will be generated.

Comment: Actually, I have made my pipeline work with two dynamic wildcards. The only restriction seems to be that I cant have two dynamic wildcards as the input to rule all. The easiest workaround is to just make a pseudo rule before rule all which takes one of the dynamic wildcards as an input, touches a dummy file, and passes that as an input to rule all.

Comment: thanks for letttimg me know I have removed the incorrect portion from the answer.  I was wrongly concluding that this applies across the Snakefile but is actually a rule limitation.  Since I used more than one dynamic always in the target rule, I never picked this caveat up. Good to know!